# Modify original ColorTable in VRT & TIFF files

Tags: gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I'm looking to modify the original `ColorTable`, when georeferencing, PNG => `gdal_translate` + `gdalwarp` => TIFF.

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs EPSG:4326 ' + file_png + ' ' + file_vrt + ' -a_ullr ' + calc_ullr
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 ' + file_vrt + ' ' + file_tiff
```

If I open the VRT file and do the edit manually, the output TIFF file is correct.
The problem is that I have 524288 files ... so I would like to do the modification automatically, via `gdal_translate`, but I don't quite understand using the parameters of the command ...

• Original VRT & TIFF files

```xml
# VRT
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
    <ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>
    <ColorTable>
      <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="255" c4="255" />
      <Entry c1="255" c2="255" c3="255" c4="255" />
      <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" />
        [...]
      <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" />
    </ColorTable>
  </VRTRasterBand>

# TIFF
  Band 1 Block=63153x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 0,0,0,255
    1: 255,255,255,255
    2: 0,0,0,255
      [...]
  255: 0,0,0,255
```

• Modified VRT and TIFF files

```xml
# VRT
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
    <ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>
    <ColorTable>
      <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="255" c4="255" />
      <Entry c1="0" c2="255" c3="0" c4="255" />
      <Entry c1="255" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" />
        [...]
      <Entry c1="255" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" />
    </ColorTable>
  </VRTRasterBand>

# TIFF
  Band 1 Block=63153x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 0,0,255,255
    1: 0,255,0,255
    2: 255,0,0,255
      [...]
  255: 255,0,0,255
```

With what settings can I get the VRT & TIFF files the way I want?

Answer (score 1):

The functional solution is to use `sed`.

```bsh
sed -i '/<Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" \/>/,/<Entry c1="255" c2="255" c3="255" c4="255" \/>/d; /<ColorTable>/r COLORTABLE.txt' $F_VRT
```

Or `COLORTABLE.txt` contains the values I want.